# Multi-Table Selecting with Count of Foreign Key Referred Rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, count, foreign-keys

I've tables related with foreign keys and i try to prepare a view to compose them via inner joins on SQL Server. I don't know if using inner join's is the way, but I can't get what I want anyway.

Tables are like below (I have more than 2 tables):

**Table1**:

```
| ID | Bla Bla... |
```

**Table2**:

```
| ID | Table1ID | Bla Bla... |
```

The query I tried is like this:

```
Select 
    Table1.ID, COUNT(Table2.ID) as FooCount
From
    Table1 
Inner Join
    Table2 on Table2.Table1ID = Table1.ID
```

The result I want to see should be this:

```
|    ID    | FooCount |
-----------------------
|    1     |    45    |
|    2     |    75    |
|    3     |    98    |
|    4     |    100   |
|    5     |    11    |
|    6     |    37    |
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try add group by Table1.ID

Comment: Group By works when i use just 2 tables, but i've tables more than 2 and it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to group by all columns in your select that aren't in your count

Comment: @MartinWilson just tried, but i get an error like "The multi-part identifier "dbo.View.ID" could not be bound.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even need a join to do this:

```
SELECT Table1Id AS ID, COUNT(*) as FooCount FROM Table2 GROUP BY Table1Id
```